# Perl - Regex to read log file

Tags: regex, perl

I read and did not find the answer. 
 I want to read a log file and print out everything after the ":" but some of the log have space before some dont. I want to match only the one with not space at the beginning.

```
_thisnot: this one has space
thisyes: this one has not space at the beginning.
```

I want to do that for every line in the file.

Comment: `"_"` is not "space", its underscore. `" "` is space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl 
use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;

my %result;
while(<DATA>) {
    chomp;
    next if /^\s/;
    if (/^([^:]*):\s*(.*)$/) {
        $result{$1} = $2;
    }
}

__DATA__
 thisnot: this one has space
thisyes: this one has not space at the beginning.
```

Comment: this is perfect,but keep in mind im scanning a log file. So I need to go over all the lines and use whatever is before the : as key, and everything after the : as value.

Comment: @NewLearner: I don't really understand what you mean. Do you want to keep all stuff in a hash?

Comment: Yesssss. That what I wanted. sorry I'm new to all this.

Comment: @NewLearner Be aware that if you use a hash, the keys will be overwritten. E.g. if you have `foo: bar` and `foo: baz`, only the later value will be in the resulting hash.

Answer (score 1):

Or you could use a one liner like:

```
perl -ne 's/^\S.*?:\s*// && print' file.log
```

Answer (score 0):

```
# Assuming you opened log filehandle for reading...
foreach my $line (<$filehandle>) {
    # You can chomp($line) if you don't want newlines at the end
    next if $line =~ /^ /; # Skip stuff that starts with a space
              # Use  /^\s/ to skip ALL whitespace (tabs etc)
    my ($after_first_colon) = ($line =~ /^[^:]*:(.+)/);
    print $after_first_colon if $after_first_colon; # False if no colon. 

}
```